# Averaged Derivative

Tags: real-analysis

I need help proving the following: If $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, prove that $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0-h)}{2h}=f'(x_0)$.

I have gotten as far as $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0-h)}{2h}= \frac{1}{2}f'(x_0)-\frac{1}{2}\frac{f(x_0-h)-f(x_0)}{h}$. I am not sure of my next step. It makes sense that for $h$ sufficiently small, that $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}f(x_0+h)=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}f(x_0-h)$. But, am not sure that this thought is correct. If there is a way that I could get a hint, and the answer, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0-h)}{h}=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)+f(x_0)-f(x_0-h)}{h}\\=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}-\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x_0-h)-f(x_0)}{h}\\\underbrace{=}_{t=-h}\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}-\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x_0+t)-f(x_0)}{-t}\\=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}+\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x_0+t)-f(x_0)}{t} =f'(x_0)+f'(x_0)=2f'(x_0).$$

Comment: Okay, but is there any particular theory behind setting $t=-h$? It makes sense that I should do this, but why is it appropriate to do so? It seems kind of not entirely justified, other than it works. Any addition links, or explanations would be helpful.

Comment: It is just a change of variable. That is, a way to write the limit in a more familiar way. But it is not necessary to be used. Note that: $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x_0-h)-f(x_0)}{h}=-\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x_0-h)-f(x_0)}{-h}=-f'(x_0),$$ just from the definition of derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try the change of variable $u=-h$.